# Cause of a complete zero-overwrite of an Access Office 365 accdb file?

Tags: ms-access, corruption

I encountered an issue with an Access 2016 (Office 365) database yesterday that caused an "Unknown database format" error.

- I saved and closed an Access 2016 (Office 365) file.
- When I reopened the accdb file, I received the "Unknown database format" issue.

Below are notes from my investigation.

- Checked the harddrive for errors using Properties | Tools from Windows Explorer.  No errors were found.
- Antivirus software was up-to-date (Norton) and had been run less
  than 12 hours ago.
- The accdb file was the correct size (147 MB).
- Opening the file as read-only in a Hex Editor, showed that the accdb file had been completely overwritten with zeros (147 MB of zeros).
- Checked System and Application events in the Event Viewer.  There were no critical errors or warnings that would shed light on this.

Since the file was completely overwritten with zeros, there was nothing that could be recovered using standard techniques.  This eliminated the use of techniques such as:

- Create a new Access accdb file and import objects from the corrupt accdb.
- Compact and Repair. Nothing to repair.
- Use a third-party repair tool such as SysTools Access Recovery. Nothing in the accdb for the repair tool to work with.

I have asked the developers in my company who are working in Access to make hourly backups to different locations on local USB drives and to different share folders on our network.  This is to minimize re-work.

We are also developing a procedure to allow us to check-in Access changes to DevOps.

Would anyone know of any causes that would result in an accdb that is completely overwritten with zeros?

If I know of a cause for this, we can (hopefully) remove the cause.

Comment: I've seen problems like this with antivirus solutions incorrectly flagging and erasing Access databases. Check the logs of any antivirus, if you're storing the file on a network drive, the servers antivirus is usually the culprit. That also means there might be a quarantined copy somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have hit the three(!) years old [lease bug](https://www.devhut.net/2018/06/13/access-bug-database-is-in-an-unrecognized-format/).

Sadly, and strangely, there is still no date for a definitive solution to this issue.

Comment: That lease bug causes corruption, but leaves databases in a state where recovery is usually trivial. That's not the case here, a full zero overwrite indicates an entirely different issue (the only times I've seen something like that is when an antivirus decides to kill a file)

Comment: I have seen this before as well.  We actually have our development and source code folders in the anti-virus exclusion list.

Comment: Well, then it is it. So why not also exclude the production files?